# Class Attribute Validation in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, while-loop

I have created a Bank_roll class for a casino game I am trying to build.

```
class Bank_roll:
    def __init__(self,total):
        self.total=int(total)
    
    def bet(self,amount):
        if int(amount) > int(self.total):
            return 'You cannot gamble money you dont have!'
        if int(amount)<=0:
            return 'You have to put some money forward'
        else:
            self.amount=int(amount)
```

When I validate the amount outside a while loop it works just fine:

```
money=input(int)
bank_roll=Bank_roll(money)
bank_roll.bet(1000)

<class 'int'>100
'You cannot gamble money you dont have!'
```

But when I try to validate inside a while loop I don't get the return statements:

```
while bank_roll.total>0:
    
    print('How much are you willing to bet?')
    amount=input(int)
    bank_roll.bet(amount)

    How much are you willing to bet?
    <class 'int'>0
    How much are you willing to bet?
    <class 'int'>40000
    How much are you willing to bet?
```

Why is this the case, and how I would go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually does return the message. You only need to print the message inside while loop:

```
print(bank_roll.bet(amount))
```